# Recreating builtin s.find('substring') function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to recreate the s.find('substring') function. the two problems I am encountering are as follows: 
 1)The ability to find the beginning index, for example:

```
Enter a phrase please"my best test ever!"
Enter a word you wish to find"best"
found first instance of letter at,  0
found first instance of letter at,  19
>>>
```

2) Assuming the correct index has been located, I expected this code segment to indicate whether or 
not the entire substring is within the string:

```
str2 in str1[i:len(str1)]
```

Whenever I test it independently of the main loop in idle, it does not work correctly.

Here is my main code:

```
str1 = input("Enter a phrase please")
str2 = input("Enter a word you wish to find")




for i in range(len(str1)):
    if str2[0] == str1[i]:
        print("found first instance of letter at, ", i)
        str2 in str1[i:len(str1)]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks mates!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should work just fine, but you are not doing anything with the `str2 in str1[..]` test and are not calculating the end point correctly; you want to use the length of `str2` here, really.

You could loop directly over `str1` and add indices with the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). You need to *add* the `len(str2)` result to `i` to find the endpoint, and make it print out the test; I used `==` here as the resulting slice should be the *same string*:

```
for i, char in enumerate(str1):
    if str2[0] == char:
        print("found first instance of letter at,", i)
        print(str2 == str1[i:i + len(str2)])
```

Demo:

```
>>> str1 = 'my best test ever!'
>>> str2 = 'best'
>>> for i, char in enumerate(str1):
...     if str2[0] == char:
...         print("found first instance of letter at, ", i)
...         print(str2 == str1[i:i + len(str2)])
... 
found first instance of letter at,  3
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a demo of an algorithm that does not use any of the wonderful tools that Python gives you, take a look at the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) method.

Here, roughly implemented in Python as if Python were Assembly:

```
  #0         1         2
  #0123456789012345678901234
S='dcdcacdcdeerecdabcddfdabc'
W=               'abc' # ^^^
m=0
i=0
while True:
    if m+i==len(S):
        break   
    if W[i]==S[m+i]:
        if i==len(W)-1:
            print 'MATCH!', m
            i=0
            m+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    else:
        i=0
        m+=1
```

Prints:

```
MATCH! 15
MATCH! 22
```